# Why blocking state-dependent operations are more convenient and less error-prone than those that simply fail?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading *Java Concurrency in Practice*. In *14.1 Managing state dependence*, it says:

> **State-dependent operations that block until the operation can proceed are more convenient and less error-prone than those that simply fail.** The built-in condition queue mechanism enables threads to block until an object has entered a state that allows progress and to wake blocked threads when they may be able to make further progress. We cover the details of condition queues in Section 14.2, but to motivate the value of an efficient condition wait mechanism, we first show how state dependence might be (painfully) tackled using polling and sleeping.

I'm not able to understand this sentence. **What is more convenient? Why is it less error-prone?**

Comment: *We cover the details of condition queues in Section 14.2, but to motivate the value of an efficient condition wait mechanism, we first show how state dependence might be (painfully) tackled using polling and sleeping.* So maybe read what comes after, and compare the two solutions to see which one is the easiest to use and understand?

Comment: @JBNizet But I'm not talking about "condition queues" and "polling and sleeping", I'm talking about "state-dependent operations that block until the operation can proceed" and "those that simply fail.".

Comment: Well, if they fail, you have to retry them again and again, and sleep to avoid eating all the CPU power doing nothing. That's the strategy used by polling and sleeping. It's not convenient and error-prone. The alternative is to use a blocking abstraction, that blocks the thread until the operation can be done. All you have to do is to call a method, and voilà.

Comment: because the user does not think what to do if the accessed object is not in desired state yet.

Comment: @Alexei Kaigorodov "does not think"? You mean "does not know"?

Comment: @JasonLaw I mean  "does not think" because he need not to know what to do. He is not facing a problem and need not to decide what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Java Concurrency in Practice*, 14.1 Managing state dependence:

> State-dependent operations that block until the operation can proceed are more convenient and less error-prone than those that simply fail.

You are asking:

> What is more convenient? Why is it less error-prone?

It is more convenient and less error-prone for the *caller* to appropriately use the operations that block to accomplish the goal of managing state dependence.  As mentioned at the end of the paragraph, the alternative to using the built-in blocking and queueing mechanisms would be "(painfully) tackled using polling and sleeping".

The authors are first talking about the underlying constructs of managing state dependence but they are introducing them by saying that for the caller to do it themselves is more difficult – more prone to errors made in the calling code.  It is convenient and less error-prone to use the blocking calls which are going to be talked about later in the chapter.